# Using DataAnnotations and attributes in Model First development

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, attributes, data-annotations, ef-model-first

I have been developing my Models "model-first" by using the EDMX designer.  I'm rather fond of it, but wondering how I can use this process to apply attributes, specifically DataAnnotations, to my model classes like so:

```
<DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, DataFormatString:="{0:d}")>
```

I'm guessing that if I type those manually onto my model classes it will get overwritten whenever I update my EDMX file.  What is the correct process here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of repeating myself formatting attributes such as `DisplayFormat` should be applied to the view models and not the models. Models contain reusable business logic. View models on the other hand are specifically designed for a given view, so the formatting should be done on those view models. A controller always passes a view model to a view.

Comment: I apologize for making you repeat yourself, I had originally suspected that was the case but didn't find much in the way of confirmation of that suspicion. A question of implementation then: Should my ViewModel inherit the model object and overload the property(s) I want to add formatting attributes for?

Comment: @Ben Finkel, the view model should not inherit from your model. Here's a typical scenario: 1. a controller action queries a repository and fetches a model, 2. the model is mapped to a view model (a tool such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could be very helpful in simplifying this task), 3. the view model is passed to the view in order to be displayed. This process works the other way round: a controller action takes a view model from a view, maps it to a model and passes the model to a repository for processing.

Comment: That's interesting because I'm surprised there isn't some auto-generated mapping code for basic situations.  However, that's a disucssion for another time and place. Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: Yes this seems overkill to have to create two duplicate models for simple applications just to be able to include data annotations on model-first generated class properties.  It's possible to do just that when using Code-First approach it seems.